# Upload fonts option is missing on Wix

Tags: wix.com

I want to use a font style that is not given on Wix. So I want to upload and use my own font. I have seen many tutorials for this but the problem is I can neither see *My Upload* option in left panel as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wddQp0DVB1M) nor in edit-text → fonts drop-down. So I am unable to upload the font.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using Safari on Mac. I opened the Wix editor in Google Chrome and I could see the upload font option there. Hope that helps.